# MySQL/Python learning error

Tags: mysql

I am currently learning the basics of creating a database and doing some line of data analysis. i have been struggling to understand how to 'start coding'
so i finally decided to come up with a simple diary project to kick start my coding life.

Here is what i have so far, in terms of python so far nothing except i managed to link python and mysql.

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| diary              |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sakila             |
| sys                |
| world              |
+--------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc diary;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| TASK_COMMENTS | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| TASK          | varchar(55)  | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| TS            | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from diary;
+---------------+---------------+---------------------+
| TASK_COMMENTS | TASK          | TS                  |
+---------------+---------------+---------------------+
| NULL          | Food Shopping | 2016-12-25 18:53:32 |
+---------------+---------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

here is the question finally:): Is it correct if i make the time stamp a primary key or is it more 'database error-free' to create an actual id instead of using automated timestamp as the pk?

also i am trying to make TASK_COMMENTS field not null aswell but i get this:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE Diary MODIFY COLUMN TASK_COMMENTS VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
ERROR 1138 (22004): Invalid use of NULL value
```

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can't alter the default value of a column to `NOT NULL` if a `NULL` value already exists. Either delete the row, or set it to something, then you can alter the column.

Using a timestamp is not a good idea for a primary key because it is very possible to get duplicate values. It's also easy not to, but it's just not a good idea. Use an id column, set the PK, and typically one would give it `AUTO INCREMENT` to ensure no duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for reply but how can this personal diary create duplicate values when the time stamp counts even the seconds. The person cant make 2 task logs at the exact second can he?

Comment: Thank you it makes a lot more sense now, i was only thinking myself as the one and the only user but having a lotmore users using this will require a id.